# Understanding the balun frequency range

Tags: rf, balun

I am exploring the balun part for my RF based application.  In many part datasheets, I see there is certain frequency range mentioned such as in [BD4859N50100AHF](https://cdn.anaren.com/product-documents/Xinger/BalunTransformers/BD4859N50100AHF/BD4859N50100AHF_DataSheet(Rev_C).pdf) part number,  4.8-5.9GHz is provided. I would like to know if this range is the operating frequency range of balun circuit, what will be the impact if I provide an RF input with a lower frequency than mentioned here?

Comment: Link the data sheet please.

Answer (score 2):

> I would like to know is this range is the operating frequency range of balun circuit, what will be the impact if i provide the RF input with lesser frequency than mentioned here?

The performance would not be as 'good'. The performance would not be specified. The performance would not be guaranteed to be repeatable.

- In a balun, you're expecting good port match, so small S11, S22 etc.
- You're expecting low loss, so S21 close to 1.
- You're expecting good balance.

These parameters tend to be best in mid-band, and (in most devices I've used and seen specified) degrade even within the stated operating band as you get close to the edges, while still staying within specification.

Operate just outside the stated band and your performance will have degraded even further, falling below specification. Datasheets often contain plots of performance over a wider frequency range than their stated range, so you can get an idea of how far the performance might degrade from these. Of course this is not covered by a specification, and the actual devices might not perform like this outside their specified range. Even if you test some actual devices, there is no guarantee that future devices will behave like this outside their range, only that they will be to specification inside their range.

Operate well outside the stated band, and the performance will be awful, maybe no better than a piece of track, maybe worse.

Answer (score 0):

> *what will be the impact if I provide an RF input with a lower
> frequency than mentioned here?*

If you look at the data sheet these two important graphs are found on page 3: -

[image]

So, in the left graph, the ability of the balun to "look like" a 50 Ω impedance pretty much disappears below about 3 GHz. In the right graph, below about 3.5 GHz the power losses would start to become significant. But, the real truth lies in figuring out how much your actual circuit (undisclosed) is affected by these things.